# Best Distributed Cache for Keeping Accesing configuration data<10 GB and access it for each record from a Flink streaming application?

Tags: redis, apache-flink, hazelcast, flink-streaming

I have data that is not going to be more than 10 GB , and i need to put it in Distributed Cache and access it for each record for validation from my Flink streaming application. Which one is best for this use case? i am confused between hazelcast and redis.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be to keep this data in Flink state, rather than in some external system.

To update the data, stream in new versions from any of the data sources supported by Flink, such as a filesystem or message queue.

Comment: i need to reload  the data each time after certain period due to changes in configuration, how is that possible in flink?

Comment: i need to get that data from MySQL after every update.... how is that possible through flink?

Comment: You could use something like https://debezium.io/ with Kafka, for example.